# Redirect all page requests to one page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect all page requests (php, if that matters) on a specific domain to a specific page (again, php) on that domain. I'm looking for a .htaccess, mod_rewrite solution for easy of implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond $1 !=index.php
RewriteRule .+\.php$ index.php [L]
```

That will redirect all requests that’s URL path ends in `.php` to the *index.php* in the same directory as the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Comment: No luck I'm afraid (doesn't seem to redirect at all). Thanks anyway.

Comment: You'll have to make sure you are allowing .htaccess rules to be run in your httpd.conf file - as well as make sure you have mod_rewrite installed. This .htaccess piece is straight out of the kohana php framework and works for a ton of people, so it's probably somewhere else in your settings.

Comment: .htaccess rules and mod_rewrite definitely available - just a question on the above: is this to match existing pages, or pages that don't exist? (My pages exist, I just want the request redirected temporarily).

Comment: Ah yes, I am specifically saying that if a page _actually_ exists, then go to it, otherwise do the redirect. In that case, remove those first two Conditions, and you should be alright.

Comment: I tried removing the first two conditions (the !-f and !-d) but nothing would come up then.  I am in the same boat of needing to redirect *everything* (whether it exists or not) to a specific file.